# how to prove by inference

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Can I apply modus ponens for 1 and 2 to get numbers 3's argument?
The end output should be $s$ and this seems too simple.

1. $(p ∨ r) → (q ∧ s)$ Premise
2. $p$ Premise
3. $(q ∧ s)$ modus ponens 1,2
4. $s$ Elimination

We need to get to $s$

Comment: Seems to be OK to me.

Comment: No, you can not. You first have to add a line between 3 and 2 with $(p∨r)$ then use modus ponens.

Answer (score 3):

Before you can conclude $q \land s$ you need to use $\lor$-Introduction $$p \rightarrow (p\lor r)$$ and then by modus ponens you can use $p\lor r$ plus the first premise to get $q\land s$.

1. $(p ∨ r) → (q ∧ s)$ Premise
2. $p$ Premise
3. $p  \lor r$ ($\lor$-introduction)
4. $(q ∧ s)$ modus ponens 1,3
5. $s$ $\land$-Elimination

Comment: Surely, you mean $p\lor r$?

Comment: so we start with $p$ then by v-introduction you get $(p∨r)$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.